# Why does ignoring SIGCHLD cause exit code -1?

Tags: php, fork, exit-code, pcntl

This code expectedly outputs "0":

```php
exec('date', $output, $resultCode);
echo $resultCode . PHP_EOL;
```

However, if I prepend this line:

```php
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

then the output is "-1".

Why?

Background: what I am trying to do is run `exec` in a forked process. The `pcntl_signal` line is required to avoid the exited children becoming zombies.

Comment: When the SIGCHLD signal is ignored, the child process is reaped immediately when it exits, and the parent can't get its exit status with `wait()`. The purpose of zombies is to keep the process data around until the parent calls `wait()`.

Comment: @Barmar That helped, thanks.